# Finding limit of a strangely defined recursive sequence

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I have problems finding limits of recursive sequence like: $a_1 = 5$ $a_{n+1} = \frac{(a_n)^2}{10n + 3} + 1$

I know that intuitively the limit will be $1$, since $\frac{(a_n)^2}{10n + 3}$ tends to 0, but I have problems proving that.

Hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First to all we'll need to show that $a_n$ is monotone, in particular decreasing by induction.

It's simple verify that $a_2<a_1$ and $a_n\geq 1$ for every $n$ because the term $\frac{a^2_n}{10n+3}$ is always $\geq 0$, now suppose $a_n<a_{n-1}$ then $a_n^2<a_{n-1}^2$ and
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2}{10(n+1)+3}+1<\frac{a_{n-1}^2}{10(n+1)+3}+1<\frac{a_{n-1}^2}{10n+3}+1=a_n
$$

Now $a_n$ is decreasing and lower bounded by $1$ so $a_n$ has got a limit: $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_n=l\in\mathbb R$. Then
$$
l=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{a_n^2}{10n+3}+1=\frac l{+\infty}+1=0+1=1
$$
then $l=1$.

Comment: Would it be enough to show that $a_n$ is non-increasing instead of showing it's decreasing?

Comment: Yes, for generic successions $a_n$ you need at least one of:
1. $a_n$ not decreasing ($a_n\geq a_{n-1}$) and upper bounded;
2. $a_n$ not increasing ($a_n\leq a_{n-1}$) and lower bounded.

Comment: For example succession $a_n=(-1)^n$ is lower and upper bounded but hasn't limit (it isn't monotone).

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that $a_n >0$ for all n.

Now prove, by induction, that $(a_n)$ is decreasing.

Hence $(a_n)$ is monotonic and bounded and therefore convergent. If $a$ is the limit of $(a_n)$ then $ \frac{(a_n)^2}{10n + 3} + 1 \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$, hence $a_{n+1} \to 1$ as $n \to \infty$.